# Slant/Fin Victory II Boiler - How do I turn on?

Tags: heating, boiler, hydronic

This summer, we moved into a home that has sub-floor heating installed. However, I have no idea how to use the boiler or turn it on.

The boiler itself (a Slant/Finn Victory II gas-fired boiler) has made some noise since we moved in but the thermostat was always set to the lowest position.

However, this morning I set the thermostat to 70 in the hopes that is all we would need to do. When checking the gauges on the boiler, though, I see the pressure at 0 PSI and temperature at 0 as well.

There is a small box toward the bottom of the boiler with a dial that offers `Off`, `On`, and `C` positions; it has been set to `On` the whole time.

What do I need to do to get the heat turned on?

Thank you!

**EDIT**
I did check our propane tank (60%) and all water valves appear to be on. I tried the reset on the boiler, per the instructions on the unit itself.

When turning the thermostat up, the unit does kick in and I can hear the electic ignition firing repeatedly. It wasn't doing that this morning. However, it does not appear to be igniting.  I will keep an eye on it, but still very interested in your expert advice.

Comment: You probably have 2 issues. 1 with with the wiring/safety switches/gas valve, and the other probably with the pressure reducing valve not letting water in. Don't try to fire a boiler with 0 psi although it could be that the gage is broken, call a professional.

Comment: @aofkj Thank you for the reply. I actually tracked the issue to the gas line coming into the house: there's no gas coming into the house. That being said, would that also cause the pressure gauge to show 0? Shouldn't there still be some water pressure?

Comment: It's a completely different issue, check reducing valve and the other  (ball/gate )vave.